# How to delay the execution of a script in Python?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm working with a Python script and I have some problems on delaying the execution of a Bash script.

My script.py lets the user choose a script.sh, and after the possibility to modify that, the user can run it with various options.

One of this option is the possibility to delay of N seconds the execution of the script, I used `time.sleep(N)` but the script.py totally stops for N seconds, I just want to retard the script.sh of N seconds, letting the user continue using the script.py.

I searched for answers without success, any ideas?

Comment: I think you want to *fork* a different process, sleep in that process and then *exec* the Bash script

Comment: If you use the `subprocess` module and create your own `Popen` object, your `bash` script won't block and you can put the `sleep` command at the beginning of it.

Comment: [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is a framework you can use for scheduling tasks (arbitrary function calls) in Python.

Comment: If your Python script exits before the timer expires, do you still want the bash script to run?

Comment: Sleeping for a fixed amount of time seems to be the wrong approach here. It would be much more usable, if your program just opened the script in the user's favorite text editor so they can make any modifications to it needed, then save and close the editor and have the modified script be executed.

Comment: @5gon12eder, ...indeed, that's the normal way to do it -- opening whichever editor is named in the environment variable `$EDITOR` (typically with a default of `vi` or otherwise something guaranteed to be available), and waiting for that editor to exit before proceeding. Witness git and svn prompting for commit messages that way, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start the script in a New thread, sleeping before running it.

Minimal example:

```
import subprocess as sp
from threading import Thread
import time

def start_delayed(args, delay):
    time.sleep(delay)
    sp.run(args)

t = Thread(target=start_delayed, kwargs={'args': ['ls'], 'delay': 5})
t.start()
```

Comment: Does this differ from what `threading.Timer` already provides in the standard library?

Comment: (btw, you've got `so` in one place, and `sp` in another).

Comment: @Charles Duffy I just die not know about `Timer`, that should be the excepted answer. Also thanks for spotting the typo

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `Timer` object from the [`threading` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects):

```
import subprocess, threading
t = threading.Timer(10.0, subprocess.call, args=(['script.sh'],))
t.start()
```

...the above running `script.sh` after a 10-second delay.

---

Alternately, if you want to efficiently be able to run an arbitrary number of scheduled tasks with only a single thread controlling them, consider using a `scheduler` from the tandard-library [`sched` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html):

```
import sched, subprocess

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
s.enter(10, subprocess.call, (['script.sh'],))
s.run()
```

This will run `script.sh` after 10 seconds have passed -- though if you want it to run in the background, you'll want to put it in a thread (or such) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should run sleep using *subprocess.Popen* before calling script.sh.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's much higher-overhead than using `time.sleep()`.

Comment: ...as I understand it the OP's argument against `time.sleep()` is that it ties up their Python script's execution flow, but blocking on a subprocess to exit will do the same thing.